# Exchange 2013 return message for old addresses

Tags: smtp, exchange-2013, auto-reply

In my company there are two kind of smtp address in exchange 2013 recipients:

```
j.deere@mycompany.com (old)
john.deere@mycompany.com (new)
```

Now I would like to remove all old addresses (j.deere) but I would like to reject emails to these addresses with a custom message such as:
"This address is out of date, please try with the full name..."

What is the best approach for this?
A virtual user with all these addresses and an auto-reply message?

Comment: What's the harm in keeping the old addresses as secondary addresses?

Comment: These are old addresses where 90% of delivered message are spam...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up an additional mailbox with a rule that sends a message back stating that the address is out of date and that the new format should be used. If you can, make this generic - eg Our new address takes the format firstname.lastname@....

Then assign all of the old email addresses to this mailbox.

If you need to set up a custom reply for each address, then I would recommend a transport rule for each address that sends a reply and then drops the message